# CustomDistribution cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: anylogic

I am studying the Distribution Center Model Cloud in Anylogic. But the first problem I am encountering is,

1. Description: CustomDistribution cannot be resolved to a type. Location: Distribution Center/Main/discrete - Function
   The CustomDistribtuion is used in a function

   int[] vals = new int[palletTypesNum+1];
   for (int i = 0; i <= palletTypesNum; i++)
   vals[i] = i;

   CustomDistribution distribution = new CustomDistribution(vals, weights, new java.util.Random());

   return (int)distribution.get();
   [image]

What I have Tried???

1. I have tried using [image]
2. I have also tried to import the following,`import com.anylogic.engine.markup.CustomDistribution;`in the import section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you need to use the constructors that code-complete shows you, either continuous, discrete or "options".

To learn how to use the constructors specifically, check the help: https://anylogic.help/advanced/functions/custom-distribution.html#creating-a-custom-distribution-programmatically

Comment: Well, I moved to using CustomDistributionDiscrete. And fixed other issues along with it. Thanks.

Comment: cool. You have to decide before writing the constructor